# Give Apache Permission To Folder

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, chmod

I've installed Centos5, installed a web server and set up virtual host. The host is pretty much set up like this:

```
> adduser user1
> mkdir -p /home/user1/public_html/domain1.com/{public,private,log,cgi-bin,backup}
> chmod -R 755 /home/user1/public_html/
```

And I've added a `VirtualHost` entry in httpd.conf that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#Blah blah blah
  DocumentRoot /home/user1/public_html/domain1.com/public
#Blah blah blah
</VirtualHost>
```

So apache can ready the directory just fine but has problems uploading files because the permission is denied. The scripting language is PHP.

How can I allow file uploads without making everything 777 permssion?

Answer (score 0):

chown the directory to match Apache's configured username/groupname, and check where PHP is putting its uploads

Apache's user/group are defined by the `User` and `Group` .conf options, and PHP's upload dir is specified by the `upload_tmp_dir` .ini option.

Answer (score 0):

make all folders 755 and change the owner to the user who is running apache. Usually in Centos should be httpd

Answer (score -1):

upload files someplace other then the docroot